# How to send json payload when executing a command from IoT Central v3 connector Logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-iot-central

In IoT Central we have a command as toggle_bulb where it accepts json object of mac and on_off value as follows:

```
{'mac': <mac address>', 'on_off': '0'}
```

[image]

when we run the command manually from dashboard we are receiving the request.payload value in the backend application.

But we have created a rule to execute the command using logic app action

[image]

payload parameter is defined as shown below for raw input

[image]

when the rule gets fired, we are receiving the method request but not receiving the payload in the backend application.

logs are as follows

```
iotcentral: Received call for bulb_state
iotcentral.py: toggle_bulb_command: iotcentral: request payload: {}
```

Please help me how to send json object to back end application when using iot central connector in logic app for executing a command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the request format isn't correct, it isn't received correctly by the device. Right now you are using this as the payload in your Logic App

```
{
    "mac": "00:17:88:01:06:3a:ec:bf",
    "on_off": "0"
}
```

Try using:

```
{
    "request": {
            "mac": "00:17:88:01:06:3a:ec:bf",
            "on_off": "0"
    }
}
```